# How to syncronize slow calculation and cache it?

Tags: multithreading, go, synchronization

In a golang backend I want to serve a value to a multiple clients, lets call it score. Score is changing with time, and its calculation is slow. Calculation does not depend on previous results. When there are no clients I dont want to calculate it at all. So calculation should happen only on request. But also there is another fact - score cannot change within 5 seconds period. So i tried different aproaches and everything has its drawbacks:

1. Does expensive calculation in absense of clients:

```
var score interface{}

// run in a separate goroutine
func calculateScorePeriodically() {
    for{
        select{
        case <-time.After(5*time.Second):
            score = calculateScoreExpensiveAndSlow()
        }
    }
}

func serveScore(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(score)
    w.Write(b)
}
```

2. Blocks all clients for a long calculation period (but actually may just serve old data to them). And you cannot move `if` outside a mutex, because then multiple client may enter calculation block simultaneously and would do calculation not within 5 seconds interval but sequentially:

```
var (
    score interface{}
    mutex sync.Mutex
    updatedAt time.Time
)

func getCachedScore() float64 {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    currentTime := time.Now()
    if currentTime.Sub(updatedAt) < 5*time.Second {
        return score
    }
    updatedAt = currentTime
    score = calculateScoreExpensiveAndSlow()
    return score
}

func serveScore(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(getCachedScore())
    w.Write(b)
}
```

How to solve both of above drawbacks?

PS. i think this is a generic problem, and a pattern - does it have a special name?

Comment: You write you don't want to calculate if there are no requests, but you also don't want to wait for the calculation when a request hits. This is contradictory. You can only serve "immediately" if the calculation happens before the request.

Comment: @icza - when serving, if data is not up to date i want to recalculate it. but if someone is already doing calculation - i may just serve old data (one that is currently cached), so just one will do update, while others will not wait for update. is that reachable?

Comment: And who does the recalculation? Another request? If that request waits for the result, why not make the new request wait for it too? Why serve the old data for the new request if the previous requests waits for the new data?

Comment: @icza not to make everyone stuck, they are fine to go with old data. but data needs to be updated at some point by at least one request. so i am trying to implement 1st scenario behaviour, in regarding to average response wait time.

Comment: Each scenario can be implemented, which one do you want? Note that your first solution has data race: access to the `score` variable must be synchronized.

Comment: @icza i can update that to `interface{}` to make in more generic

Comment: And what's wrong with your 2nd approach? It serves old data if they are valid (no more than 5 sec old), and if cached data is old, it recalculates it once. Yes, others wait for that too, but that's because data older than 5 sec is not acceptable. This wait can only be avoided if calculation happens before the request (see my first comment), but you wrote you don't want to calculate if there are no requests.

Comment: @icza in 2nd i want others not to wait but serve data older than 5 seconds. but still have it recalculated once if its older than 5 seconds. ideally i want to make so that no one waits at all. if data is older we need to recalculate it. but its okay to serve old data during recalculation period

Comment: @icza it feels like I need a separate goroutine, which  triggers calculation by a chan message. And skips calculation if it's not time for it. So I am not locking clients at all and dont do calculation in absense of clients. What do you think? Is there more lightweight sync scheme rather than a channel?(because I actually don't need a queue, but just a signal that I want to recalc)

Comment: Yes, that's a solution I'd prefer too, suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions. A simple solution is to have a designated goroutine for calculation, to which you can signal a need for recalculation by sending a value on a channel. The send may be non-blocking, so if a calculation is in progress, nothing will happen.

Here's a reusable cache implementation:

```
type cache struct {
    mu      sync.RWMutex
    value   interface{}
    updated time.Time

    calcCh     chan struct{}
    expiration time.Duration
}

func NewCache(calc func() interface{}, expiration time.Duration) *cache {
    c := &cache{
        value:   calc(),
        updated: time.Now(),
        calcCh:  make(chan struct{}),
    }

    go func() {
        for range c.calcCh {
            v := calc()

            c.mu.Lock()
            c.value, c.updated = v, time.Now()
            c.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    return c
}

func (c *cache) Get() (value interface{}, updated time.Time) {
    c.mu.RLock()
    value, updated = c.value, c.updated
    c.mu.RUnlock()

    if time.Since(updated) > c.expiration {
        // Trigger a new calculation (will happen in another goroutine).
        // Do non-blocking send, if a calculation is in progress,
        // this will have no effect
        select {
        case c.calcCh <- struct{}{}:
        default:
        }
    }

    return
}

func (c *cache) Stop() {
    close(c.calcCh)
}
```

Note: `Cache.Stop()` is to stop the background goroutine. After calling `Cache.Stop()`, `Cache.Get()` must not be called.

Using it for your case:

```
func getCachedScore() interface{} {
    // ...
}

var scoreCache = NewCache(getCachedScore, 5*time.Second)

func serveScore(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    score, _ := scoreCache.Get()
    b, _ := json.Marshal(score)
    w.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: interesting, but i think that channel is overkill here. How to implement a sync primitive, which from sender perspective will look like infinite length buffered channel (e.g will never block) and from reader's side it would be only 2-state semaphore (e.g locked/unlocked)? when sender writes to such primitive it becomes unlocked. when reader reads from such primitive it blocks while it is in locked state, switch goes when its becomes unlocked, any read from unlocked atomically converts it to locked again - where is such thing in go? how to implement it without chan?

Comment: or like a selectable waitgroup, with negative counter support, where reader will select on wait, and successfull `Wait` will immediately atomically call `Add` to lock it again. and writer will just send `Done`. it seems that we are just missing one important sync primitive in go. I cannot construct it from what we have, to have all properties (buffered channels have finite length, waitgroup does not work with negative numbers and its wait does not reset it back to locked state)

Comment: Why is using a channel "overkill"? It's not.

Comment: because a channel is a queue. and for solving this task a queue is not required, but what is required is a kind of 2-state semaphore. so chan its an extra thing for nothing. for example i cannot define a channel of infinite length, and if i will run 1m parallel requests at once and channel buffer will be only for 1k, then after 1k requests they will start waiting on a calculation goroutine, because sending to notification channel will be blocked until reader will done calculation and start reading from it. so channel could fit, but looks an inappropriate solution here

Comment: @xakepp35 I used an unbuffered channel. And I used non-blocking send. So no, there is no waiting queue in my solution. No matter how many goroutines there are, no matter how many use the cache, there will be no one waiting on the channel's queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've implemented, correlates with icza's answer, but has some more features:

```
package common

import (
    "context"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

type (
    CachedUpdater func() interface{}
    ChanStruct    chan struct{}
)

type Cached struct {
    value        atomic.Value  // holds the cached value's interface{}
    updatedAt    atomic.Value  // holds time.Time, time when last update sequence was started at
    updatePeriod time.Duration // controls minimal anount of time between updates
    needUpdate   ChanStruct
}

//cachedUpdater is a user-provided function with long expensive calculation, that gets current state
func MakeCached(ctx context.Context, updatePeriod time.Duration, cachedUpdater CachedUpdater) *Cached {
    v := &Cached{
        updatePeriod: updatePeriod,
        needUpdate:   make(ChanStruct),
    }
    //v.updatedAt.Store(time.Time{}) // "was never updated", but time should never be nil interface
    v.doUpdate(time.Now(), cachedUpdater)
    go v.updaterController(ctx, cachedUpdater)
    return v
}

//client will get cached value immediately, and optionally may trigger an update, if value is outdated
func (v *Cached) Get() interface{} {
    if v.IsExpired(time.Now()) {
        v.RequestUpdate()
    }
    return v.value.Load()
}

//updateController goroutine can be terminated both by cancelling context, provided to maker, or by closing chan
func (v *Cached) Stop() {
    close(v.needUpdate)
}

//returns true if value is outdated and updater function was likely not called yet
func (v *Cached) IsExpired(currentTime time.Time) bool {
    updatedAt := v.updatedAt.Load().(time.Time)
    return currentTime.Sub(updatedAt) > v.updatePeriod
}

//requests updaterController to perform update, using non-blocking send to unbuffered chan. controller can decide not to update in case if it has recently updated value
func (v *Cached) RequestUpdate() bool {
    select {
    case v.needUpdate <- struct{}{}:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func (v *Cached) updaterController(ctx context.Context, cachedUpdater CachedUpdater) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case _, ok := <-v.needUpdate:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            currentTime := time.Now()
            if !v.IsExpired(currentTime) {
                continue
            }
            v.doUpdate(currentTime, cachedUpdater)
        }
    }
}

func (v *Cached) doUpdate(currentTime time.Time, cachedUpdater CachedUpdater) {
    v.updatedAt.Store(currentTime)
    v.value.Store(cachedUpdater())
}
```